# Back Button in ActionBar at MainActivity

Tags: java, android, button, back

I have implemented a Back-Button for all Activities except the `MainActivity`.
My Problem is that i have a Back-Button in that `MainActivity` too.

Hopefully I've imported the right class:

```
    import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        [...]
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
        case R.id.ueber:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, menu_main_Activity.class));
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

AndroidManifest:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/levox"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".ListViewActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ListTasksActivity"
        android:label="@string/projekte"
        android:parentActivityName=".ListViewActivity">
        </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ListSingleTaskActivity"
        android:label="@string/tasks"
        android:parentActivityName=".ListTasksActivity">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".menu_main_Activity"/>
</application>
```

Why i get a Back-Button at `MainActivity` too?

Comment: change this setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false), instead of that use your app icon to exit application(whatever you want to use),or set another icon using getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu);

Comment: so easy thank you... Can you tell my why my app crashes if i click at the back button on other activities?

Comment: Thank you but i cant find getSupportActionBar()

Comment: sorry for getSupportActionBar use getActionBar, and post your code in question,  whatever you have used to go previews activity, or add logs

Comment: My other Activities doesn't contain any code for back button... just the mainactivity... do i have to put some code for back button for the other activities?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first question is:
What do you mean by "Back-Button"?

- Do you mean the button which is in each Android-Device on the bottom-left? You can't disable that one. But it is called "***Back-Button***" in the Android-universe actually. Sometimes it is even part of the hardware!
- Do you mean the button which is shown by a little arrow directing to the left, just next to the App-Icon on the top left of your application? That button is called "***Up-Button***" in the Android-universe.
  This one is shown in your MainActivity because of this line in your code:

  ```
  getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
  ```

  in the method

  ```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  ```

  So you should take away this line.
  To disable not just the **appearance** of the button but also the **functionality** of it, you have to take a look at this part of the code:

  ```
   switch (item.getItemId()) {
  case android.R.id.home:
      NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
      return true;
  case R.id.ueber:
      startActivity(new Intent(this, menu_main_Activity.class));
      return true;
  }
  ```

  Here, you have to remove the part

  ```
  case android.R.id.home:
      NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
      return true;
  ```

EDIT:
But if you actually **want to have the "Up-Button"** visible inside an Activity, you

- have to set the code

  ```
  getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
  ```

  in the onCreate()-method of that Activity!
- provide a parent-Activity in your Manifest.xml (what you're doing already), for example:

  ```
  android:parentActivityName=".ListViewActivity"
  ```
- and put the part

  ```
  case android.R.id.home:
      NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
      return true;
  ```

  into the Activity which shall have got the "Up-Button".

If you mean anything else, please specify your question and provide more code :)

Some useful links:

- To learn more about implementing the "Up-Button", read [Providing Up Navigation](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html)
- To learn more about the differences between "Up" and "Back" in Android, read [Navigation with Back and Up](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html)

Comment: I agree, thanks, this solution worked for me. Sometimes late nights you forget everything you copied from other classes to save time. LOL

Answer (score 0):

Am using java and my   minSdk = 19 and targetSdk =31. I added the following code inside the onCreate method

```
  getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Then i overide onSupportNavigateUp(). outside onCreate. as follows.

```
@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    onBackPressed(); // goto previous activity when actionbar backbutton clicked
    return super.onSupportNavigateUp();
}
```

Comment: Can you [edit] in some more explanation on how this relates to the question?